# TikZ: vertically aligning text in nodeparts

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, vertical-alignment, nodes

I can't seem to vertically align text in different nodeparts of the same node.

This MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{bplus}=[rectangle split, rectangle split horizontal, rectangle split ignore empty parts,draw]
\tikzstyle{every node}=[bplus]
\node {\huge{I} \nodepart {two} \huge{h} \nodepart {three} \huge{g} \nodepart {four} \huge{x} } ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

gives:

[image]

I'd like to have the text aligned on some baseline, preferably centred as if a complete word.

I tried

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style = {anchor = base}] ...
```

amongst other things, but it didn't work.

Comment: ...trying to adapt an example from here:   
    
    http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17331/how-do-i-draw-a-b-tree-in-latex.  
    
...when I use variable height letters, it causes the above problems.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add the option `rectangle split part align=base`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{bplus}=[rectangle split, rectangle split horizontal,
    rectangle split ignore empty parts, rectangle split part align=base,draw]
\tikzstyle{every node}=[bplus]
\node {\huge{I} \nodepart {two} \huge{h} \nodepart {three}
    \huge{g} \nodepart {four} \huge{x} } ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: node parts with base alignment]

Comment: pgfmanual 2.10 cvs 52.6 Shapes with Multiple Text Parts page 497 !

Comment: @JasperHabicht Maybe the issue is this one?