# Using TikZ to create a tree with root node at the bottom

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

Is it possible to draw a tree with the root node at the bottom? The image below demonstrates what I'd like, but is upside down.

[image: Tree diagram]

I've looked into similar questions, most notably

[How do I draw a B+ tree in latex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17331/how-do-i-draw-a-b-tree-in-latex)

But they haven't been entirely helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `grow` key, described on page 218 of the pgfmanual:

> This key is used to define the direction in which the tree will grow.
>   The direction can either be an angle in degrees or one of the
>   following special text strings: `down`, `up`, `left`, `right`, `north`, `south`,
>   `east`, `west`, `north east`, `north west`, `south east`, and `south west`. All of
>   these have “their obvious meaning,” so, say, `south west` is the same as
>   the angle `-135◦`.

In your case, you can use `grow=up`; a little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
[level distance=10mm,
every node/.style={fill=red!60,circle,inner sep=1pt},
level 1/.style={sibling distance=20mm,nodes={fill=red!45}},
level 2/.style={sibling distance=10mm,nodes={fill=red!30}},
level 3/.style={sibling distance=5mm,nodes={fill=red!25}}]
\node  {31} [grow=up]
child {node {30}
child {node {20}
child {node {5}}
child {node {4}}
}
child {node {10}
child {node {9}}
child {node {1}}
}
}
child {node {20}
child {node {19}
child {node {1}}
child[missing]
}
child {node {18}}
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Depending on the desired order for the nodes, you could use `grow'` instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
[level distance=10mm,
every node/.style={fill=red!60,circle,inner sep=1pt},
level 1/.style={sibling distance=20mm,nodes={fill=red!45}},
level 2/.style={sibling distance=10mm,nodes={fill=red!30}},
level 3/.style={sibling distance=5mm,nodes={fill=red!25}}]
\node  {31} [grow'=up]
child {node {30}
child {node {20}
child {node {5}}
child {node {4}}
}
child {node {10}
child {node {9}}
child {node {1}}
}
}
child {node {20}
child {node {19}
child {node {1}}
child[missing]
}
child {node {18}}
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, cheers :) I knew it would be something straight forward